# how to include php file in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 files abc.php and xyz.php. When i open in mobile, it includes abc.php and on desktop xyz.php is included. I have included these files below but it's not working. Any suggestions welcome.

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            <?php include ('abc.php');?>
            } else {
            <?php include ('xyz.php');?>
            }
 </script>
```

Comment: Try using ajax to call functions from php files that you need, not including the files

Comment: You can't do that - you would need to use php to determine which file to include. Using the `useragent` is not reliable anyway but you could use php to process the useragent rather than javascript

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side language. You cannot load like that.
So use ajax instead.

```
<script>
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        var include = "abc.php";
    } else {
        var include = "xyz.php";
    }
    $.ajax({
         url:"url to a function where you can include specified file",
         type:"POST",
         data:{file: include},
         success: function(){
              // you can get executed content of a file here. 
         }
    });

</script>
```